# Data flow among Inplutsplit, RecordReader & Map instace and Mapper

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

If I've a data file with 1000 lines.. and I use `TextInputFormat` in my `map` method for my Word Count program. So, every line in the data file will be considered as one `split`.

A RecordReader will feed each line(`or split`) as `(Key, Value)` pair to the `map()` method.

As per my understanding.. 1000 times `map()` method should execute for each line or record.

means how many `Mappers` will run??
sorry confused here.. `map()` method is just an instance of mapper right.. so how many map instances per Mapper task is decided based on what???

Note: When I executed `WordCount MapReduce` Program for 1000 lines of data.. I see the number of `Mappers` as 2. so 500 `map` instances run for each `map tasks???`

Please correct my question if I asked it wrong.

Comment: what is the size of data ? What is HDFS block size? Do you have specified any input split in your code?

Comment: The size of data is 2.08 kb
HDFS Block size is default (64 MB)
I don't have any specific input split in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How mappers get assigned**

Number of mappers is determined by the number of splits determined by the `InputFormat` used in the Map/Reduce job. In a typical `InputFormat`, it is directly proportional to the number of files and file sizes.

Suppose your HDFS block configuration is configured for 64MB(default size) and you have a files with 100MB size then it will occupy 2 block and then 2 mapper will get assigned based on the blocks

Suppose if you have 2 files with 30MB size(each file) then each file will occupy one block and mapper will get assigned based on that.

Suppose you have a file with 60MB then it will occupy 1 block but if you have specified input split size in your code, say split size is 30MB then 2 mapper will get assigned for this job.

[`RecordReader()`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/RecordReader.html)- The record reader breaks the data into key/value pairs for input to the Mapper.It takes Parameters:

**split** - the split that defines the range of records to read.

[`InputSplt()`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/InputSplit.html)- Get the size of the split, so that the input splits can be sorted by size.

If you have not specified any `InputSplit` size then it will take whole block as one split and will read data and generate key, value pair for Mapper.

In your case 2 Mapper is assigned. It indicates you have specified the `InputSplit` size or your data resides in 2 block.

This [link](https://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2013/05/27/understand-recordreader-inputsplit/) can be helpful to understand the record reader and input split.

Answer (score 0):

First it depends upon the size of the hdfs block.
There is a difference in number of mapper the program invoked wrt number of times the the maper code ran.

The single mapper instance will run as much times as the number of line in case of your code as the input format is textinput format.But the number of mapper will run that purely depends upon blocksize.

Comment: So, there is a difference between number of map tasks and number of number of map instances..???
Map instances are based on lines(for TextInputFormat) and number of Mappers are based on the InputSplit size.??